# How to get asymptotic running time?

Tags: java, algorithm, performance, asymptotic-complexity, cumulative-sum

I do not know how to get exact Asymptotic Complexity as following question asks me to solve.

Here is Question:

[image]

Everything I learned from class is that, if there exists "for loop" that runs N times, or recursively call "recursive method" N times, then either one is O(N). This is practically all the base knowledge I know of.

***Question 1) What answer says about "N(N+1)/2", is this same as "O(N(N+1)/2)"?***

Also, the answer says followng "On iteration i, both add and trimToSize require that i array elements be copied to a new array.", I think it says this because it calls both "list.add()" and "list.trimToSize()" N times.

From my perspective, this looks more like just O(N)... because since it adds ith element N times using "list.add()" and also array-copies element N times through "list.trimToSize()". Thus, N + N <= 2N so O(N) where witness C=2 and k=1, not O(N(N+1)/2). However, my answer is wrong. Therefore,

***Question 2) I just do not know how to obtain N(N+1)/2 as answer says.***

Thank you very much if you can answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> From my perspective, this looks more like just O(N)... because since it adds ith element N times using "list.add()" and also array-copies element N times through "list.trimToSize()". Thus, N + N <= 2N so O(N) where witness C=2 and k=1, not O(N(N+1)/2).
>
> However, my answer is wrong.

Yes.  It is.

You are treating each call to `trimToSize` having a constant cost.  That is not correct.  If you look at what `trimToSize` does, you will that *each call* is copying all of the elements (so far) to a new array.  That is NOT a constant cost

- In the 1st call to `trimToSize` the array length is 1, so you copy 1 element.
- In the 2nd call to `trimToSize` the array length is 2, so you copy 2 elements.
- ...
- In the Nth call to `trimToSize` the array length is N, so you copy N elements.

Add that all up and you get `N(N+1)/2` for all of the `trimToSize` calls.

(And, in fact, given the way that the code is using the `ArrayList`, each time that `add` is called, the list's backing array will need to be reallocated.  So the same calculation applies there too.)

---

<sup>Note that `O(N(N+1)/2)` is the same complexity class as `O(N^2)`.  You can prove this from first principles.)</sup>

Comment: ah now i got it, thank you very much! so O(N) from running "list.add()" N times, and also O(N(N+1)/2) running time from "list.trimToSize()" method. So in total by adding them, "N + N(N+1)/2". But you said O(N(N+1)/2) can be O(N^2).. so it can be replaced to "N + N^2". To calculate big oh from it, "N + N^2 < N^2 + N^2 = 2N^2" thus O(N^2) with witness of C=2 and K=1, which is same as O(N(N+1)/2). Hope I got it... Thank you.